# How do i set ther innerText/innerContent of a list to the content of a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I'm fairly new to JavaScript so forgive me if this code is terrible. What I'm trying to do is have a user select a state from a form and return 5 cities. This is the code I have so far?

html w/ bootstrap classes

```
<div class="row row1">
<div class="col-md6>
<div class="input-group">
<form>
 <select class="form-control" name="states" id="uStates">
  <option value="AL">Alabama </option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska </option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona </option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
  <option value="CA">California</option>  
 </select>
</form>
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="60000">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button id="uBtn" onClick="populateCities">GO!</button>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
 <ul class="list-group cities">
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city1">1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city2">2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city3">3</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city4">4</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city5">5</li>
 </ul>
</div>
 </div>
```

JS

```
var stateData = [ 
  ["Birmingham", "Montgomary", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Tuscaloosa"],
  ["Anchorage", "Juneau", "Fairbanks", "Ketchikan", "Sitea"],
  ["Phoenix","Tucson","Scottdale","Mesa","Tempe"],
  ["Little Rock","Fayetteville","Hot Springs","Fort Smith","Bentonville"],
  ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco","San Diego","Sacramento","Oakland"],
 ];

function populateCities(){

 var state=document.formName.States.options;
 for (var i=0; i<state.length; i++){
    state[i]=stateData[i]
    for (var j=0; j<5; j++){
        document.getElementById("city1").innerContent(stateData[0]);
        document.getElementById("city2").innerContent(stateData[1]);
        document.getElementById("city3").innerContent(stateData[2]);
        document.getElementById("city4").innerContent(stateData[3]);
        document.getElementById("city5").innerContent(stateData[4]);
    }
 }
}
```

I've been at this for quite some time. My loops may be incorrect and my function obviously isn't working. If someone could help I would truly appreciate it. Also, I'd like the answer in plain JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot a `"` on line 2: `<div class="col-md6">` and a `"` on line 17: `<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="uBtn" onClick="populateCities">GO!</button>`

Comment: The first is a copy/paste mistake, but thanks for the other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a couple of changes to your code, hope it's what you wanted.

I just wanted to add that it's bad practice to use `onclick=populateCities`. You should wire the event from javascript `document.getElementById ("uBtn").addEventListener ("click", populateCities, false);`

Also, `document.formName.States.selectedIndex;` is what you were looking for. You don't need anything else to loop through the array.

```js
var stateData = [
  ["Birmingham", "Montgomary", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Tuscaloosa"],
  ["Anchorage", "Juneau", "Fairbanks", "Ketchikan", "Sitea"],
  ["Phoenix", "Tucson", "Scottdale", "Mesa", "Tempe"],
  ["Little Rock", "Fayetteville", "Hot Springs", "Fort Smith", "Bentonville"],
  ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "San Diego", "Sacramento", "Oakland"],
];
  
document.getElementById ("uBtn").addEventListener ("click", populateCities, false);
  
function populateCities() {
  console.log("populateCities called");
  var state = document.formName.States.selectedIndex;
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      document.getElementById("city"+(j+1)).innerText = stateData[state][j];
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row row1">
  <div class="col-md6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <form name="formName">
        <select class="form-control" name="States" id="uStates">
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="CA">California</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="60000">
      <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="uBtn">GO!</button>
  </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
    <ul class="list-group cities">
      <li class="list-group-item" id="city1">1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item" id="city2">2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item" id="city3">3</li>
      <li class="list-group-item" id="city4">4</li>
      <li class="list-group-item" id="city5">5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) your loop is doing absolutely nothing don't hard code the indexes if you're gonna loop

2) change innerContent() to innerHTML = stateData[i]

3) html tags don't use camelCase

4) you have multiple missing end quotes in your html

```js
//move the click listener to your code

var btn = document.getElementById("uBtn");
btn.addEventListener('click', populateCities);

var btnD = document.getElementById("uBtnDyn");
btnD.addEventListener('click', populateCitiesDynamic);

//grab a reference to state picker
var states = document.getElementById("uStates");

// change stateData to an object so you can reference the state

var stateData = {
  AL: ["Birmingham", "Montgomary", "Huntsville", "Mobile", "Tuscaloosa"],
  AK: ["Anchorage", "Juneau", "Fairbanks", "Ketchikan", "Sitea"],
  AZ: ["Phoenix","Tucson","Scottdale","Mesa","Tempe"],
  AR: ["Little Rock","Fayetteville","Hot Springs","Fort Smith","Bentonville"],
  CA: ["Los Angeles", "San Francisco","San Diego","Sacramento","Oakland"],
 };

function populateCities(){
 // get the cities for the current state
 var cities=stateData[states.value]
 console.log(cities)
 
 //loop through the cities
 for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
   var li = document.getElementById("city"+(i+1))
   li.innerHTML = cities[i]
 }
 
}


//for a more advanced option, add the list items dynamically
// this way your states don't need the same number of cities
var cityList = document.getElementById("cityList")

function populateCitiesDynamic(){
  cityList.innerHTML = "";
 // get the cities for the current state
 var cities=stateData[states.value]
 console.log(cities)
 
 //loop through the cities
 for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
   var li = document.createElement("LI")
   li.id = "city"+(i+1)
   li.innerHTML = cities[i]
   cityList.appendChild(li);
 }
  
 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="row row1">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="input-group">
<form>
 <select class="form-control" name="states" id="uStates">
  <option value="AL">Alabama </option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska </option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona </option>
  <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
  <option value="CA">California</option>  
 </select>
</form>
  <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" placeholder="60000">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="uBtn">GO!</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="uBtnDyn">GO Dynamic!</button>
  </span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row row2">
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
 <ul class="list-group cities" id="cityList">
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city1">1</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city2">2</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city3">3</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city4">4</li>
  <li class="list-group-item" id="city5">5</li>
 </ul>
</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @EricaKnight that only really applies if you're diggin up an old post or commenting on someone elses stuff. Thanks are always appreciated!

Comment: @ErikaKnight I would recommend you check out the codecademy tutorial on javascript: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript